# Use a map ID in my code to display this custom map on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-maps, embed

(very weak level in frontend)

I basically follow this tuto :
https://youtu.be/CdDXbvBFXLY
the coder uses a code slightly different that what we have now on Google Platform, instead of

```
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?keyYOURKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

she uses

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&map_ids=YOURMAPID&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
    defer
  ></script>
```

Anyway, doesn't work for me.

Now on the Google documentation they mention Map Id's feature only on the function Initmap.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/get-map-id

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
zoom: 8,
mapId: 'MAP_ID'
});
```

here is my test page. It actually doesn't display my custom map, only the reel Google map, because of the coordinates I put in :
https://eostation.xyz/

```
<script> function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 69.4865, lng: 88.3972 },
        zoom: 13,
        mapID: '6c69da475e7f7301'
      });
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: talnakh,map: map});
}
```

[I don't really understand what is a InitMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykR3G.png)

In other words, I need the correct syntaxe to call my custom map and not Google map.
When I say "custom map", i don't mean a map with markers, i don't mean a trail of landmarks done on Google Map, I'm talking about a fictionnal map, for a game, using GoogleMap API.

Thank you

Comment: What's the value of `talnakh`?

Comment: I actually got rid of :

"let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: talnakh,map: map});
}
window.initMap = initMap;

Comment: *I don't really understand what is a InitMap* - That is the name of your function: `function initMap() { ... }`. And it would seem that within that function, like @PrerakSola mentions, `talnakh` is not defined. Can you post the rest of your code, so that we can see where and how you define the `talnakh` variable (since it seems to be a global variable)?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a fictional google map without any landmarks or labels. Then you can use [Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?csw=1#StyledMaps) to style the map within the initMap function.

You initMap function could be like this:

```
function initMap() {
  const position = { lat: 31.225196, lng: 121.492271 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: position,
  });
  map.set('styles',[{
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }
  ]},{
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]}
  ]);
}
```

Your map will [look like this](https://snazzymaps.com/style/24088/map-without-labels) after using setting the custom style.

Comment: That is amazing ! Unfortunately my project (an ARG) requires a lot of landmarks and a street view, so Google Map API is really my tool